# Creating a grid of tiles in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a project and the user asked if they could have something like this.

[image]

Grid lines are there as a guide.

I understand I could use columns but the item that's tripped me up is the longer image.

Is there a way to have a row that spans many rows?

Or is it best to have columns within columns and then seperate out each element?

Comment: Please provide a code for what you have tried so far!

Comment: you can make it for desktop screen alone but when going for responsive image will brake the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below Column technique

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uurzr45k/3/

```
img{width:100%;  margin:10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Masonry Plugin can help you achieve this layout > [Check it out](http://masonry.desandro.com/)